# SQL - Need to update a value in a table based the number of relations its row has to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

```
Instructor
ID | name | dept_name | salary

Teaches
ID (FK) | section_id | course_name
```

I need to multiply each instructor’s salary by the number of course sections they teach. I cannot figure out how to do this in SQL with the `UPDATE` statement and `COUNT()`. Could anyone help? Anything is appreciated.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Mysql <> sql server <> sqlite. Please don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Instructor i
SET Salary = Salary * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teaches t WHERE t.ID = i.ID)
```